# Multiple WYSIWYG editors with settings teeny => true

Tags: wysiwyg

I have multiple WYSIWYG editors on a page using wp_editor. I am trying to add the setting 'teeny' => true, but it seems to only apply to the first editor instance.

All subsequent editors are just plain text areas and I get a javascript error in the console. `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"`

```
<?php
            $content = $field['url'];
            $settings = array(
                            'textarea_name' => 'url[]', 
                            'teeny' => true,
                            'raw' => true, 
                            'editor_class' => 'movie_description_editor' 

                            );
        ?>

        <td><?php wp_editor($content, 'movie_description-'.$num, $settings ); ?></td>
```